# Is it possible to use conditional statements to modify parameters at compile time in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423218/how-do-i-calculate-constant-values-across-several-modules-at-compile-time-in-ver) explains how to use Verilog parameters to combine constants from different modules at compile time. I am wondering if it is also possible to use conditional statements to modify parameter values at compile time.

Specifically, if the calculated total of the parameter values exceeds some maxLength, I want the parameter to 'wrap around' maxLength and be left with the remainder instead.

Pseudo-code example:

```
module toplevel {
    defparam myPole.offset = 95;

    pole myPole();
}

module pole {
    parameter offset = 0; // default value, overwritten by 95

    localparam x = 1;
    localparam y = 2;
    localparam z = 3;
    localparam maxLength = 100;

    localparam transitionConst = x + y + z + offset; // total is 101, this works as expected

    if(transitionConst > maxLength){
        transitionConst = transistionConst - maxLength;
    } // transitionConst should wrap around 100, and be left with 1
}
```

I looked at compiler directive tutorials at [asic-world.com](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/compiler1.html) and [TestBench.in](http://www.testbench.in/TB_22_COMPILATION_N_SIMULATION_SWITCHS.html), but the only if statements they describe are ifdefs. So, I suspect that Verilog does not support generic compile-time conditional statements. Is there a different approach I could use to accomplish this?

(P.S. I've seen Verilog Q&A on both EE.SE as well as StackOverflow. Which is the more appropriate community?)

Comment: Whatever you do, do ***not*** use `defparam`. It is strongly discouraged and the standardization body would loved to drop it if they could.

Comment: I think this community is more appropriate.  Stackoverflow describes itself as "_Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers_", which is more SW centric, whereas, while ASIC/FPGA _design_ **uses** SW to describe the HW, it isn't the same as writing SW in terms of OOP aspects.  ASIC/FPGA SV verification space, on the other hand, is OOP, but because it is still "HW engineering", I think you would be hard-pressed to get much help on stackoverflow for SV, and more likely to get it here.  I could be wrong, but I would come here first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator `condition ? true_expression : false_expression` as long as everything within the expression is a parameter or literal constant.

```
localparam transitionConst = (transitionConst <=  maxLength) ? x + y + z + offset : transistionConst - maxLength;
```

You can also use functions to define parameters, as long as all the function inputs are parameters or constants as well.

Comment: That is also known as a Ternary operator/statement if you want additional information

Answer (score 0):

You can do it it in your script (e.g. makefile) at compile time using `maxLength` as an input to an if-then-else statement that assigns a parameter value.  Then pass these values using whatever mechanism the simulator you are using requires for you to specify the value on the command line (`-g` for Questa).  Thus, for Questa/Modelsim, you would build your command line adding `-g <name>=<value>` to your `vsim` command.  Look at command line reference for the details.